# VirtualBox - Bring both screens to the front

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors

**Question:** Is there a way to configure a VirtualBox dual screen setup so that, when activated, it brings not one but both screens to the front?

**Context:** I got a virtual machine in VirtualBox. My host machine has two screens, and I configured the VM to use two screens as well, which works fine after I followed [these steps](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-enable-dual-or-multi-monitor-support-in-Oracle-Virtual-Box).

When I use another application on my host machine, the VM screens will move to the background (obviously). Now, when I activate one of the VM screens, I'd like both screens to move to the foreground. By default, this doesn't happen, which sometimes results in me waiting for a result on one screen, while there is actually a dialog box waiting for my input on the other screen, which is hidden behind some host application.

Both the host and the client are running Windows 7 Pro.